# Implementing partition_by function in Erlang

Tags: algorithm, erlang

I'm trying to create a partition-by function in Erlang where the first argument is a predicate function.

```
step(_, [ ]) ->
  [ ];

step(N, C) ->
  [_ | T] = C,
  case (N > 0) and (length(C) > 0) of
    true ->
      step(N - 1, T);
    false ->
      C
  end.

drop(_, [ ]) ->
  [ ];

drop(Number, Collection) ->
  step(Number, Collection).

partition_by(_, [ ]) ->
  [ ];

partition_by(F, Collection) ->
  [H | T] = [Collection],
  Head_value = F(H),
  Run = [H | lists:takewhile(fun(E) -> Head_value =:= F(E) end, T)],
  [Run | partition_by(F, erl_funcs:drop(length(Run), Collection))].
```

But when calling it:

```
partition_by(fun(E) -> E > 0 end, [-44444, -4555555, 455555]).
```

I'm getting:

```
[[[-44444,-4555555,455555]],[[-4555555,455555]],[[455555]]]
```

Not exactly what I'm thinking of.  Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how it should work when you didn't provide desired output but I try guess.

```
partition_by(F, [H|T]) ->
  partition_by(F, F(H), T, [H]).

partition_by(F, HV, [H|T] = L, Acc) ->
  case F(H) of
    HV -> partition_by(F, HV, T, [H|Acc]);
    _ -> {lists:reverse(Acc), L}
  end;
partition_by(_, _, [], Acc) -> {lists:reverse(Acc), []}.
```

Comment: Yes exactly, that is the output I'm looking for. What is wrong with original algorithm?

Comment: What is the performance impact of calling lists:reverse/1 on big lists?

Comment: It is O(n) time and O(n) space operation implemented in C as BIF. Anyway you can try and measure. I bet mine code will be better.

Answer (score 1):

This line `[H | T] = [Collection],` is wrong in your code. 
I change it to `[H | T] = Collection,`.

I think you want fetch one element from list `Collection`, so you need `[H | T] = Collection`.
If you use `[H | T] = [Collection]`, that means `H = Collection, T = []`.

Here is my full code.

```
-module(wy).
-compile(export_all).

drop(_, []) ->
     [];
drop(0, Collection) ->
    Collection;
drop(Number, [_H | T]) ->
    drop(Number - 1, T).

partition_by(_, [ ]) ->
  [ ];

partition_by(F, Collection) ->
  [H | T] = Collection,
  Head_value = F(H),
  Run = [H | lists:takewhile(fun(E) -> Head_value =:= F(E) end, T)],
  [Run | partition_by(F, ?MODULE:drop(length(Run), Collection))].

main() ->
    T = partition_by(fun(E) -> E > 0 end, [-44444, -4555555, 455555]),
    io:format("~w~n", [T]).
```

The output is:`[[-44444,-4555555],[455555]]`

Comment: But if you tried this list:  [-44444, -4555555, 455555, -344300, 89894]  the output is: [[-44444,-4555555],[455555],[-344300],[89894]]

Comment: @Chiron: If this is not expected output it is probably because you didn't provided one in your question.